# syntax error, unexpected (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Tags: php

I want to use variable inline, but I got syntax error.

Code is below

```
$json_output = @file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D$v['id']");
```

And I got this error

> FatalErrorException in 04fbb7d79f886667a5b215427ff1f592 line 12:
>   syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: I know that it is probably top secret, but which is `line 12`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to rewrite this line, because you can't use an array inline in the way you are currently:

`$json_output = @file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D$v['id']");`

These will work:

`$json_output = @file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D{$v['id']}");`

`$json_output = @file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D" . $v['id']);`